# Full screen plot in qt

Tags: qt, plot, qcustomplot

I'm using QCustom Plot to produce graphs in qt but the graph produced is too small for my purposes even after I maximized the widget size in the design tab. Is there any way to make a graph/plot full screen? 
When I run my code and maximize the gui window the plot itself remains unchanged in size.

```
void Cpp_Fire::on_manual_fire_clicked()
{


    // Code for graph
    // generate some data:
    QVector<double> x(variables.nr_samples), y(variables.nr_samples);

    for (int i=0; i<variables.nr_samples; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = x_axis[i]; 
        y[i] = y_axis[i]; 
    }


    ui->customPlot->addGraph();
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");

    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(x[0], x[variables.nr_samples-1]);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 65000);
    ui->customPlot->replot();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the setViewport() function? It's usually used when exporting the graph but allows you to resize the graph beyond the widget size

Comment: Please specify what you have done in detail.

Comment: @ Bosman. How would I do this?    @Tay, I created a graph using qcustomplot, when I maximize the pop-up window the size of the widget containing the graph remains unchanged and I would like to maximize it or at least enlarge it.

Comment: @Duanne You should use Qt layouts. See the documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html . You can simply do it in designer : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html

Comment: @Duanne It's better to provide some `codes` or **images** ...etc to help others answer your question. It seems that you didn't use layout to manage your QCustomPlot class widget just like Nejat said. You need to add the QCustomPlot class widget to your gui window's layout.

Comment: @ tay, yes I didn't use the layout. I'm using the links nejat posted and i've updated the question to show the part of the code related to plotting

Answer (score 0):

For setting your Qcustomplot window in fullscreen:

```
setGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry()); /* in your QMainWindow derivative constructor */
```

Now your graph must auto scale:

```
ui->customPlot->rescaleAxes(); /* after the graph data is filled */
```

If it is not enough, you can always add the ability to zoom or drag the graph to get the view you prefer:

```
ui->customPlot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag | QCP::iRangeZoom);
```